# Variables in java not holding their value inside loop

Tags: java, variables, loops, scope

I am iterating through possible radii for a circle (r), and when I find potential candidates I basically want to push them onto a stack. I only need to remember the last two radii and the color of the circle they correspond to, So I've created four integers to store these variables. However, the print statement I have included always yields values of 0 for both variables.

```
 //small stack to hold values of previous circles
            int small_radius    =   0;
            int small_color     =   0;
            int med_radius      =   0;
            int med_color       =   0; 
            //iterate through possible radii       
            while (r<max){
                //check for possibility of a circle
                if(detectCircle(x,y,r,img,g)){
                    //confirm it is a circle and store its color
                    int large_color = confirmCircle(x,y,r,img,g);
                    if(large_color != -1){
                        //if it is a circle, compare the medium circle against the current one and the small one
                        //check if the current circle and small circle do not immediately surround the medium circle
                        boolean matches_small = (med_radius-1 == small_radius && med_color == small_color);
                        boolean matches_large = (r-1 == med_radius && large_color == med_color);
                        if(!matches_small && !matches_large){
                            //if it is a circle of single line thickness, draw it
                            System.out.println("med_radius: "+med_radius+" small_radius: "+small_radius);
                            drawCircle(x,y,r,img,g);
                        }
                        //now push the current circle onto the stack.
                        small_radius = med_radius;
                        small_color  = med_color;
                        med_radius   = r;
                        med_color    = large_color;  
                    }
                }
                r++;
            }
```

edit: for those wondering what confirmCircle looks like, here it is, but it shouldn't make a difference.

```
 static int confirmCircle(int cx, int cy, int r, BufferedImage img, Graphics2D g) {

    int color = img.getRGB(cx,cy+r);

    int f = 1-r;
    int ddF_x = 1;
    int ddF_y = -2 * r;
    int x = 0;
    int y = r;


    while(x < y) {
        if(f >= 0) {
            y--;
            ddF_y += 2;
            f += ddF_y;
        }
        x++;
        ddF_x += 2;
        f += ddF_x;

        if(img.getRGB(cx+x,cy+y) != color){color = -1;}
        if(img.getRGB(cx-x,cy+y) != color){color = -1;}
        if(img.getRGB(cx+x,cy-y) != color){color = -1;}
        if(img.getRGB(cx-x,cy-y) != color){color = -1;}
        if(img.getRGB(cx+y,cy+x) != color){color = -1;}
        if(img.getRGB(cx-y,cy+x) != color){color = -1;}
        if(img.getRGB(cx+y,cy-x) != color){color = -1;}
        if(img.getRGB(cx-y,cy-x) != color){color = -1;}
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger point to? Did you try using it?

Comment: Without the code of `confirmCircle`, there's no way to know what's wrong. If it returns -1 everytime, you would get the results you see. We need more informations to be able to help in a significant way.

Comment: Your println statement is before the assignment of med_radius.  Should it be using r to display med_radius?  Since med_radius is equal to r.

Comment: How many times do you print out the values? The first two iterations of the loop (assuming r starts at 0) will print 0 for both of them, but after that it looks like the variables should be incremented properly.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau if it returns -1 the print statement is not called.

Comment: @ManuelQuinones it should be displaying the values assigned during the previous iteration.

Comment: @jonhopkins it prints many times and they all ready 0, and yea thats what I thought too :/

Comment: How do `detectCircle()` and `confirmCircle()` look like?

Comment: Strange.. I just tested your code (max = 10, faked the methods to just return values that will get inside the loop, and forced the booleans to be false so it guarantees printing) and everything printed out incremented like it should be...

Comment: @agarrow Sorry, meant 0 not -1 in my last comment. Does it prints more than once?

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying to help! Yes, it prints many times.

Comment: @jonhopkins damn, I've been staring at this for too long and I really can't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @agarrow I honestly can't see what's wrong with it either. Are you 100% sure that none of the variables are global and being changed somewhere else? That's the only thing I can think of right now that would cause that problem..

Answer (score 1):

There is no code in this sample that assigns to any of the four variables.

If you are doing the assignment inside `confirmCircle()`, then the problem is that you are expecting `int`s to be pass-by-reference when they are pass-by-value in Java.

In other words:

```
int a = 4;

public void changeA(int someVar) {
    someVar++;
}

changeA(a);
System.out.println(a);  //prints 4, not 5.
```

Comment: confirmCircle() returns the RGB value of the circle, which I then assign to a variable inside this loop.